# In Excel, is there a way to link a dropdown menu to specific data?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, drop-down-menu

Essentially what I have done so far is create a dropdown menu using the Data Validation tab within the 'Data' tab in Excel. Using a SS I will show what exactly I'm trying to do.

If this can also potentially be done with a vba macro please let me know.

Essentially, when I change the data (where the blue arrow is) I want different data values to appear in the table (in the red circle) for each different item in the dropdown box
[image]

Please let me know if this is possible in Excel, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Yes you can do it with formulas or VBA, but since there are no real details in your question (where is the source data, and how would it be selected?)  it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ah sorry about that, haven't chucked the data in the table yet. Does the picture link work? - Pretend there are a bunch of values within B$4:B$15, what I would like is once the dropdown value in B1 is changed, a different set of data which is linked to the dropdown value to appear.

Comment: Where does that data appear *from* though ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have a bunch of different sheets where I'm hoping to connect data from, however I could manually copy, paste the data into B$4:B$15 and then link it to the indvidual drop-downs if that is possible?

Comment: Still not clear - *exactly how* does the value in the drop down determine what shows up in the table below?

Comment: ^ That's what I'm trying to find out - if I put a bunch of values within the table, would there be a way to connect it to individual values within the dropdown box.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion - I'm new to stackflow haha! - Do you know if there is a way to easily show my excel values in the future?

Comment: You can share a workbook via Google/Dropbox/etc

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry I never got back to you, I ended up stumbling upon a video which pretty much answered what I was trying to do, for anyone interested here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ4GCFN8tpk

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the effort in trying to help though! I'll use your advice to try make my questions a bit clearer, next time I'll try to show what I'm trying to do with the data! :)